# There’s or There is?

Tags: grammar

There’s antiques, knickknacks, and many more at the thrift store. Or should it be, There will be an abundance of items this Saturday at the thrift store.

Comment: Your two example sentences are very different. I think your question might be clearer if you changed only the part of the sentence you are uncertain about. But to answer the question in your title: *there's* is simply a contraction of *there is*.

Answer (score 1):

"Antiques" and "knickknacks" are plural nouns. As you're listing a few items, I'd suggest using "there are" instead.

> There are antiques, knickknacks, and many more items at the thrift store.